# Syntax error in .bashrc after installing gsutil

Tags: bash, gsutil

On a Linux machine, I'm trying to install gsutil following the instructions on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install. During installation, I answered "yes" to everything and left things at their default values.

Now however, if I open a new terminal it starts with a bash error:

```
bash: /home/kurt/.bashrc: line 119: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
bash: /home/kurt/.bashrc: line 119: `fi'
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$
```

The offending lines are contained in the following snippet of my `.bashrc` file:

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
  source '/home/kurt/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
fi
  source '/home/kurt/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
fi
```

The error occurs at the second-last `fi` statement. Indeed, it looks like the last two `fi`s are not matched by any `if`. I could just comment out the last three lines, but I'm not sure if that would break the functionality. Any advice?

Comment: Why are the last 3 lines hanging without any logic?

Comment: That puzzles me as well. It would seem unlikely that Google would ship code with syntax errors in it, yet these lines seem to have been added by the installation program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your `.bashrc` snippet, you won’t break any functionality by removing the last two `fi` keywords.  It’s possible that there’s a corresponding `if` keyword earlier in the file but going by the indentation and content of the preceding block (configuring bash completion), I doubt it.

I’d guess that the missing lines are checking that the two files exist (and are readable) before trying to `source` them:

```
if [ -r '/home/kurt/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then
  source '/home/kurt/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
fi

if [ -r '/home/kurt/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' ]; then
  source '/home/kurt/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
fi
```

It looks like there is a bug in the installer that generated those lines. To be on the safe side, I would re-download the package and run the installer again.